# change opacity and animated that with react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, mouseevent

i started a simple project with react.in my project i have a paragraph and when mouse hover on paragraph (mouse enter event) a square appears under the paragraph and when hover out from paragraph(mouse leave event) that square disapear.but this occure so fast so i want changing this  smoothly and i want use opacity and change that from 0 to 1 and reverse when my events occure.but I do not know what to do to change the opacity with animation in react.

this is my appjs

```js
import './index.css';
import React, {useState} from "react";

function App() {
    const [isShowSquare, setIsShowSquare] = useState(false);
    const showSquare = () => {
        setIsShowSquare(true);
    }
    const hideSquare = () => {
        setIsShowSquare(false);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <p onMouseEnter={showSquare} onMouseLeave={hideSquare} style={{display:'inline-block'}}>Hover Me</p>

            {isShowSquare ?
                <div className='square'>
                </div>
                : null
            }

        </div>

    );
}

export default App;
```

and this is my index.css

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.square{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #61dafb;
}
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me

Comment: did you check the answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method without using `useState` though.
I don't know if this part is important, but have a  look at my
[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/young-fog-gxze7)

First of all you need a css class to define the opacity the method and how much time it will take. Also, your first `square` class should have opacity: 0, meaning non visible.

When mouse is over text, then you add the extra class to the element.

```
  const showSquare = () => {
    div.current.classList.add("square-full");
  };

  const hideSquare = () => {
    div.current.classList.remove("square-full");
  };
```

---

```
.square.square-full {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}

.square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #61dafb;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Updated answer: No need for `ref`

Just use the following code

```
export default function App() {
  const [ isShown, setShown ] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div>
      <p
        onMouseEnter={() => setShown(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setShown(false)}
        style={{ display: "inline-block" }}
        class="paragraph"
      >
        Hover Me
      </p>

      <div className={`square ${isShown ? 'square-full' : ''}`}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

along with the extra class i mentioned before

Comment: thanks man but can you write this with query selector because i read some where that It is better not to use query selector in react.(For performance reasons)

Comment: @Poldark changed the sandbox to use `ref`. i dont know why this didnt work at first. weird

Comment: if you see sth over and over again, you realize how it can become better. new and updated answer without `ref` :)

Comment: thank you very much.i will check this solution And I will tell you the result

Comment: I Love u man that's worked. i have also a question about swiper js package can i send link of my question to you?

Comment: i guess i cant help you with this but send it so i can see just in case :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191175/change-how-slides-are-displayed-in-swiper-js

Answer (score 1):

Appearing is easy, and for disappearing I found a solution like this;

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {

  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
  const [disappear, setDisappear] = useState(false)



  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p onMouseLeave={()=> {
        setDisappear(true)
        setTimeout(()=>{setVisible(false)
        setDisappear(false)}
        , 1000)      
      }} onMouseEnter={()=> setVisible(true)}>Hide/Show square </p>

{visible && <div className="square"  
style={{
width: 100,
height: 100,
animation: disappear ? "disappear 1s ease" : "appear 1s ease"
}}> </div> }  

 </div>
  );
}
```

For the animations in css ;

```
//style.css

.square {
  background-color: red;
  animation: appear 1s ease;

}
@keyframes appear {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}



@keyframes disappear {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

So what happens here is that we have a keyframe on our css for the opacity initially. So this works fine, tricky part is disappearing. When we set the visible state to false React immideately removes our element, so we have setTimeOut to stop React for 1 second. In that 1 second we apply our animations, it runs smoothly on me. Go ahead and try.