# Change how slides are displayed in swiper js

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, swiper.js

i used swiper js slider in my project.i need to know can i change default slide of my slider or not.forexample my slides are slide1 slide2 slide3 Etc and in my page swiper js showed slide 1 By default.i want show slide2 by default .can i achive that by swiper?

this is my swiper config

```js
window.videoSlider = () => {
    var sliderSelector = '.video-slider',
        options = {
            init: false,
            loop: false,
            speed: 800,
            spaceBetween: 0,
            slidesPerView: 3, // or 'auto'
            // spaceBetween: 10,
            centeredSlides: true,
            effect: 'coverflow', // 'cube', 'fade', 'coverflow',
            coverflowEffect: {
                rotate: 0, // Slide rotate in degrees
                stretch: 0, // Stretch space between slides (in px)
                depth: 585, // Depth offset in px (slides translate in Z axis)
                modifier: 1, // Effect multipler
                slideShadows: true, // Enables slides shadows
            },
            pagination: {
                el: ".testemonial-pagination",
                clickable: true,
            },
            grabCursor: true,
            parallax: true,

            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.video-next',
                prevEl: '.video-prev',
            },
            breakpoints: {
                1440: {
                    slidesPerView: 2,
                    spaceBetween: 0
                },
                1200: {
                    slidesPerView: 2,
                    spaceBetween: 0
                },
                992: {
                    slidesPerView: 1,
                    spaceBetween: 0
                },
                768: {
                    slidesPerView: 1,
                    spaceBetween: 0
                },
                480: {
                    slidesPerView: 1,
                    spaceBetween: 0
                },
                320: {
                    slidesPerView: 1,
                    spaceBetween: 0
                },
                1: {
                    slidesPerView: 1,
                    spaceBetween: 0
                },
            }
        };
    var mySwiper = new Swiper(sliderSelector, options);

    // Initialize slider
    mySwiper.init();
}
```

and this is my slider
[image]

i want First show second slide because i want my user can From the beginning, he can go to both sides.(left and right by default swiper showed slide 1 so user can't move the slide to right i khow i can use loop property in swiper but i won't that)
I would be very grateful if anyone could help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#parameters) all you need to do is add an extra parameter `initialSlide` which defaults to 0 (0-index) and set the index you want,

so your case this would be 1.

```
    spaceBetween: 0,
    initialSlide: 1,
    slidesPerView: 3, // or 'auto'
```

Comment: thanks so much . I hope to see you some day and be my guest for lunch. :)))